# Rstudio cannot show outline of knitr with chunk label

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

In [knitr manual](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/),

> in theory, the chunk label should be quoted as well, but for the sake
> of convenience it will be automatically quoted if you did not quote it
> (e.g. `{r, 2a} will become` {r, '2a'})

But with `rstudio 1.2.5042` , `R 3.5.3`, and `knitr 1.2.6`, `{r, 2a}` is not considered as chunk in outline(`ctrl+shift+o`),but `{r 2a}` will be in outline.

What's the problem? Should I add comma between `{r` and chunk label?

Comment: @Phil before this turns into an edit war, why do you think that the RStudio tag does not apply here? What is or what is not displayed in RStudio's outline is related to ... RStudio.

Comment: I misread and thought the issue was with with the knitting, and not with the outline pane in the IDE. Apologies. Anyway, to answer the question, the chunk is named after whatever follows `r` before the comma, so you shouldn't use the comma until you want to provide further arguments specific to the code chunk.

Comment: To add, I would contact Yihui directly about this and ask if the comma in the link is a typo. It seems odd to me that he displays it like that.